# Rails 3 I want to remove some part of string from the other string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, string, gsub

I am working on rails 3  and ruby 1.9.3 I want ro remove

> "[\

part from

> "[\"NAS1149C0363R"

I am working with sub method but could not achieve so Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

`"[\"NAS1149C0363R".sub(/\[\"/,'')`

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean you want to remove `[\"`, not `"[\`.

```
"[\"NAS1149C0363R".delete('["')
```

Comment: This is the cleanest of all suggestions